# IOS Offline Login

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication

Stange question, I'm looking to create an app for the company I currently work for which will hold all passwords for the software and platforms we use. I would like to be able to create some kind of login or authentication without connecting to the internet or using a post to HTTP.

Is this kind of thing possible? Even if I was to keep it to one username and password across the board. Or is it going to be better to only distribute to people that I know?

The only reason I want to do this is so that when downloaded from the App Store it would be only engineers that could login.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For this you can add json file that contain all the data of the users for initial state and for user registration you can use core data. But you want to syncing with registered data and json file you need to fire silent api call to server.